# ¿Como puedo cargar mas datos en un ListView en Android cuando se llega al fin de la lista?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Buenas, en mi proyecto necesito cargar una sección de noticias en mi `ListView`, obviamente ya los puedo listar, el problema es que como tengo muchas noticias lo que quiero es cargarlas por partes, es decir supongamos que tengo 3000 noticias, lo que quiero es cargar primero 500 noticias, cuando el usuario termine de ver las noticias obviamente tendría que **deslizar hacia abajo** para poder cargar las 500 siguientes.

Lo que quisiera saber el método de **deslizar hacia abajo** para cargar nuevas noticias( obviamente sin perder las noticias anteriores ya que estoy haciendo uso de los view holders), espero que me deje entender. Saludos amigos programadores.

Comment: Siempre se recomienda compartir el código ya hecho. Así la pregunta queda más claro y se te puede ayudar aun más concreto.

Answer (score 2):

Si te entiendo bien quieres cargar una parte de la lista entera y seguir cargando más bloques cuando el usuario llega al fin de la lista. Para eso tu puedes usar un `OnScrollListener`. Primero defines tu `OnScrolllistener` como clase interna de la `ListView`:

```
class MiOnScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // comprobar si llegemos al fin de la lista
        distanciaDeFin = totalItemCount - firstVisibleItem - visibleItemCount;
        // si la distancia hasta el fin de datos ya cargados es menor a 5, cargamos más
        // la distancia para cargar puedes adaptar parra llegar al "feel" que quieres
        if (distanciaDeFin < 5) cargaProximoBloque(totalItemCount);
    }

    @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
    }
```

En tu `ListView` tienes que hacer dos cosas:

1. Colocar el escuchador en `onCreate`
2. Implementar `cargaProximoBloque`

En `onCreate`:

```
setOnScrollListener(new MiOnScrollListener());
```

Y la implementación de `cargarProximoBloque`

```
void cargarProximoBloque(int totalItemCount){
    // tu código para buscar el bloque desde totalItemCount +1
    // y assumiendo que usas un ArrayAdapter construido con una lista:
    adapter.addAll((Collection) proximoBloque);
}
```

Espero que eso te alcance para completar tu actividad. Cualquier duda no dudes de preguntar.

> **Un consejo:**
> Usa un `ArrayAdapter`, pero asegúrate que lo construyes con una lista como parametro (`ArrayList`por ejemplo) en el constructor. Hay dragones en esta clase. Si lo construyes con un arreglo simple, el adapter no te permite agregar más datos después.